# Regex pattern UNMATCH in VB.NET or C#

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

need a pattern to match a string which should NOT be --

```
777777777
888888888
999999999
```

or start with `00` or `02` or `04`.

when i tried to go create a pattern to match the above requirements, i got it done by -

```
Dim _pattern6 As String = "^(7+|8+|9+|(00|07|08|09|17|18|19|28|29|43|48|69|70|78|79|80|96|97).*)$"
```

could not get the NOT MATCH part done.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is **[negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)**.

```
@"^(?!([789])\1{8}$|0[024]).*$"
```

The negative lookahead `(?!...)` means "whatever follows this position cannot match any of these patterns." So `(?!7{9}).*` means "any string of characters (`.*`) that doesn't start with nine `7`s in a row." The `([789])\1{8}$` is shorthand for 9 repeated digits. It means "Either 7, 8, or 9 followed by itself another 8 times."

Tested on RegexPlanet: http://fiddle.re/tz8p

Comment: I've never tried putting two `$` 's at the end of a regex, does it work? (though I suppose you aren't matching it just looking at it the first time). So, +1 to you sir.

Comment: @jb - Correct: The first `$` is just saying that whatever follows is going to be something other than 9 of the same number [7-9] and an end-of-line. `$` is valid anywhere in a regex as long as the result still makes sense, so `(^foo$|^bar$|^baz$)` would work fine, whereas `foo$bar$` wouldn't. Thanks for the +1. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to match to unwanted parts. If that returns true, you know the attempt to "not match" would have been false, and vice versa.

Answer (score -2):

Here you go

```
[^(7{9}|8{9}|9{9}|00|02|04)]+
```

Comment: This isn't how negative character classes work. If you don't get a runtime error, I'm pretty sure this is going to look for literal versions of the special characters in the group.

Comment: this simplifies down to `[^024789]+` ie "anything other then these numbers"

Comment: @Justin's right; `[^(7{9}|8{9}|9{9}|00|02|04)]` is equivalent to `[^024789(){}|]`, which matches any **one** character as long it's not one of those in the list.